# Plotting a dictionary of counters as a multi bar graph in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I have a python dictionary of Counters as an output as shown below:

```
{0:Counter({1:100}),1:Counter({1:100,2:30,3:50},2:Counter({2:70,4:10})}
```

How do I plot this as a multi bar graph with key being the X-axis and frequency of each element in the Counter as the Y-axis?.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Maybe provide a drawing of what you want? Should there be values 0,1 and 2 in for the x axis and 2 bars of 100 for the value of 1? The desired outcome is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
from collections import Counter
pd.DataFrame({0:Counter({1:100}),1:Counter({1:100,2:30,3:50}),2:Counter({2:70,4:10})}).T.plot.bar()
```

[image]